# C# SQL command to get the count when a certain element appears in an xml index in

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, xml

I am trying to work with a SQL command in C# on some test data. My table schema contains a timestamp, and an XML file. I want to get the count of a certain instance in the XML file. For example, I want to get the count of every time a `<tests>` index contains A. I have a rough idea of what I want to do, but I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Database example

```
Name      Timestamp                 Metadata
test1     1/1/2004 12:00:16 AM      <metadata>
                                       <tests>A</tests>
                                    </metadata> 
test2    1/2/2004 12:00:19 AM       <metadata>
                                       <tests>B</tests>
                                    </metadata>
```

File 1

```
 <metadata>
        <tests>A</tests>
    </metadata>
```

File 2

```
<metadata>
    <tests>B</tests>
</metadata>
```

I know my command should look something like this, but I don't know how to properly execute this.

```
string sql = "SELECT YEAR(Timestamp) * 12 + MONTH(Timestamp), Month(Timestamp) as month, Year(Timestamp) as year, xmlCol.value('(/metadata/tests)[1]', 'varchar(50)') WHERE xmlCol.Value EQUALS 'A' as Month, Year, Count FROM dbo.TestTable;"
```

Comment: Is that really MySQL? Your query looks more like SQL Server to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use count function you must group by other fields or use functions for them too

```
SELECT YEAR(Timestamp) * 12 + MONTH(Timestamp), Month(Timestamp) as month,
Year(Timestamp) as year, xmlCol.value('(/metadata/tests)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
 AS Value WHERE xmlCol.Value  EQUALS 'A' FROM dbo.TestTable AS Temp
```

so you can select them AS temp and then select from temp using aggregate function for all fields.

```
select min(Year),min(month) ,count(Value ) from temp
```